# Replacing inactive moderators during beta

Tags: feature-request, moderation

The current moderators were [announced two years ago](https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98/moderator-pro-tem-announcement). and since Kristan haven't been seen for about a year now, and graduation from beta is nowhere in sight, should we find someone else as a replacement?

I'm wondering about this because if there is an odd number of moderators, there would be a tiebreaker in case difference in opinion arise.

Comment: Sorry about that; I got a new job so I don't have the time I used to. If a suitable replacement can be found, I won't object.

Comment: Where would you think there could be a tiebreaker? Being a moderator on a Stack Exchange site, I don't see any case where having two (or four) moderators would cause a tiebreak. In fact, on the site I moderate, there are four elected moderators.